# Search for multiple terms in R

Tags: r, regex

I am looking for a way to search multiple terms like egrep can do but in R.

For example:

```
cat fruit | egrep 'apples|grapes|oranges'
```

Comment: reproducible example please?  probably `grep("(apples|grapes|oranges)",fruit)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that in R, just use the `grep` function

```
fruit<-c("apples","bananas","tomatoes","grapes")
grep('apples|grapes|oranges', fruit, value=TRUE)
# [1] "apples" "grapes"
```